# Need assistance conceptualizing as database design for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database

I am busy trying my first app with MongoDB and I keep reverting to Relational Db thinking every time I try to approach the design.

I was wondering if anyone could recomned a design for the following proble.

I have the following entities
- Branches 
- Clients
- JobCards
- Files
- Emails

Branches each have there own clients
Branches have job Cards
Clients have Job Cards

Each job card has attached files and attached emails.

Eveythime I try to desinge this Iland up will a million tpye tables and the like

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I see it. Branches and Clients will have a one-to-many relationship with table clients having a foreign key for branch_id. Meaning a client will belong to one branch but a branch will have many clients.

Then the same relationship for Clients and JobCards with a foreign key in job cards for clients_id. Meaning a job card will belong to one client but a client can have many job cards. You can then see in what branch the job card is by referencing the foreign key branch_id in table clients. *Note(This will not work if a branch can have a job card of its own).

Then the last part will be easy with table Files and table Emails referencing jobcard_id as a foreign key. Will edit table structure now.

```
Branch Table:
branch_id
//all columns for branch table

Clients Table:
client_id
//all columns for client table
branch_id // foreign key constraint

JobCard Table:
jobcard_id
//all columns for jobcard table
client_id //FK you can check with this in which branch the job card is, because the corresponding record for client_id will have a branch_id.

Files Table:
file_id
//all columns for files table
jobcard_id //FK

Emails Table:
email_id
//all columns for emails table
jobcard_id //FK
```

Comment: That looks like a rather relational data model for MongoDB -- foreign key constraints and normalised tables?  I would have expected some mention of considerations for linking vs embedding.